# Excel function for First Row and Last Row of group

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a gate keeping report with a number of entry/exit times for an employee over a 24hr period.

[image]

**I need another formula to go into I40 which is the difference between the first entry time - last entry time for each employee eg. I40 = F50 - D40.**

Dont worry about the formula regarding the subtraction of dates as I have this.  I really just need the formula that will allow me to get the Last Exit time cell and the First Entry time cell for each employee.

Answer (score 0):

**The best way is to always store datetime values** (ie, `2018-05-24 13:454`) instead of just the times.  You could still *display it* as a time by changing the cell's formatting to a time format.

> Shortcut to Number Formatting options: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

There are many advantages, including that "regular math" will still work even if a shift starts in a different day than it ends.

If you must stick with only times, you can still calculate it correctly (up to a `23.9`-hour shift) with an `IF` statement to ***add a day*** if the returned value is **negative**.

For example, if your existing formula works for same-day shift, and is:

```
=F50-D40
```

...then you could change it to:

```
=IF(F50-D40<0,F50+1-D40,F50-D40)
```

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**How to use dates and times in Excel**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/214094/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-excel)
- Office.com : [**Add or subtract time** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad)

---

## EDIT:

Looking at your question again, perhaps I misunderstood what you were trying to ndo. It's a little unclear, but you mention the fist and last times.

If you mean the "earliest and latest", you can get those using `MIN` and `MAX`.  If the crossing-midnight is an issue here too, you'll need to see my first suggestion above, or else add a "helper column" to determine which times are before which.

Storing datetime is still best and this all would have been avoided.

Comment: Ok sorry I probably added too much info which was making it unclear.  Ive highlighted the question now which will hopefully make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

try the below to get the difference in hours.

```
=(E50+F50)-(C40+D40)
```